# Save Draft and Preview not working (1 post)

Tags: draft, previews

I'm on WP 4.3, latest. The "Save Draft" and "Preview" functionality aren't working. Drafts are not being saved. Clicking that button takes me to the home page of my website. Same with Preview.

I googled and looks like this is an age-old problem with WordPress, many threads of discussion simply suggest deactivating all plugins, changing themes to default, etc. I've done all of this, cleared cached, restarted browsers.

Nothing works. What else is there to do? If so many people are having this problem both on wordpress.org and wordpress.com, is there an official fix for this? Thank you for any help or pointers.

Comment: I had similar problems with the default and standard WordPress installation. caused by the firewall configuration in the server. Unfortunately we can not help you, it is a job for the support team of your hosting company.

Answer (score -3):

Try to disable the mod security through your cpanel. 
Or you can ask your host to disable mod security for you.

Comment: Why, how it should help?